# Docker dynamic IP, Server ip white listing

Tags: docker, whitelist

I have some issues with docker, my problem is as follows.

Currently my environment is running in MONOLITH and planning to migrate microservices using Kubernetes and Docker. Currently my server  ip is white listed by the third party services to call their API but in the case of DOCKER, container IP is dynamic. So it's not possible to white list the ip frequently.  Please help me to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Outgoing connections will always appear to be from the host making the container, regardless of whether the client is in a container or running directly on the host.

Nothing outside the current host ever sees the container-private IP addresses.  (In a Kubernetes context, nothing outside the cluster ever sees the cluster-internal IP addresses.)  You can almost always completely ignore these addresses.  An external API will have no idea whether your client is running in a container or directly on the host.